# Validation in IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that its a simple question but i have tried many times for my code check validation but its not working. When i click register button it takes me to next page instead of validating my form.My code is

```
- (IBAction)Register:(id)sender {
    if ([self.name.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSString *message = @"Name";

        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your Name"
                                                                       message:message
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        });

    } else if ([self.email.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSString *message = @"Email";

        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your Email Address"
                                                                       message:message
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        });

    }else{

        NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
        NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
        //Valid email address

        if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:_email.text] == YES)
        {
            // NSLog(@"Correct Email");
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *message = @"Invalid Email";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Email Format Incorrect"
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }

        if ([_code.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Code"]) {
            NSString *message = @"Select Country Code";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }


        if ([self.mobileCode.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSString *message = @"Enter Mobile Code";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }

        if ([self.number1.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSString *message = @"Enter Your Number";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }





    }
    [self Account];



}
```

Comment: 1. Did you assign a serge in Storyboard? 2. I don't see any debug `NSLog` in your function. 3. What are the values in the input field?

Comment: you are being taken to next page probably because of `[self Account]`. Is `Account` method used to present next screen ?

Comment: Your code calls `[self account]` no matter what validation happens. And why do you automatically close any alert after 1 second?

Comment: It may case that you directly give navigation from Storyboard. Check once in storyboard about it.

Comment: [self Account] in this my API is running and registering the data from user. @TejasK

Comment: No im not going through segue i'm using method when data is register. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: What you do in [self Account] method?

Comment: It's hard to tell why you are being taken to the next screen from this code, where and how are you presenting the next screen. Show us that code.

Comment: Also if this a demo project, share it on Git.

Comment: [self Account]; it will true condition. if you want  use each validation message sould be use    retun;

Comment: see my answer , @umer , alsways use method to validate your TextField , you have to just call method to validate all Your condition

Comment: Okay big thanks. @Dhiru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are calling API even all validation passed or failed. I put small logic when to call API. Kindly check my below and let me know if you have any doubt.

```
   - (IBAction)Register:(id)sender {

        BOOL isValidationSuccess = TRUE;
        if ([self.name.text isEqualToString:@""]){

            // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
            isValidationSuccess = FALSE;
            NSString *message = @"Name";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your Name"
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        } else if ([self.email.text isEqualToString:@""]){

            // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
            isValidationSuccess = FALSE;

            NSString *message = @"Email";

            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your Email Address"
                                                                           message:message
                                                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

            int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            });

        }else{

            NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
            NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
            //Valid email address

            if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:_email.text] == YES)
            {
                // NSLog(@"Correct Email");
            }
            else
            {
                // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
                isValidationSuccess = FALSE;


                NSString *message = @"Invalid Email";

                UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Email Format Incorrect"
                                                                               message:message
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            }

            if ([_code.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Code"]) {

                // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
                isValidationSuccess = FALSE;


                NSString *message = @"Select Country Code";

                UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                               message:message
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            }


            if ([self.mobileCode.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

                // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
                isValidationSuccess = FALSE;


                NSString *message = @"Enter Mobile Code";

                UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                               message:message
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            }

            if ([self.number1.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

                // You need to change the flage when you get error in your code
                isValidationSuccess = FALSE;


                NSString *message = @"Enter Your Number";

                UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                                               message:message
                                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

                dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                });

            }





        }


        // This comes TRUE means you have pass your all validation.
        if(isValidationSuccess)
        {
            /// You can call for register
            [self account];
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot. @Nirmalsinh

Answer (score 2):

Best way to validate Your `TextFiled` is

Create  a method for validation

```
-(BOOL)validation
{

  if (self.name.text.length==0){
// Show alert enter Name
return NO;

}

if ([self.email.text.length==0){
// Show alert enter Email
return NO;

}

if ([_code.titleLabel.text.length==0){
// Show alert Select Country
return NO;

}

// Similarly Create method to validate your email
if (![self validateEmailString:self.email.text]){
// Show alert invalid email
return NO;

}

// and so on check your validation 

//Finally retrun YES , validation Over
return YES;
}
```

**Uses**

```
if ([self validation])
{
  // validation over than call your API
[self Account];
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got my answer. @Dhiru